# Array from different classes

Tags: objective-c, arrays, xcode, class, nsobject

i have a class Devices and several subclasses like mobiles, watches etc.

I just wondering is it possible to create an array from all of these subclasses? I have to create objects from class1 class2 etc and put them to an array. This array must contain objects from different classes. The array must have 200 elements. And can you please give an example.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *yourArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

ObjectType1 *object1 = [[ObjectType1 alloc] init];
[yourArray addObject: object1];

ObjectType2 *object2 = [[ObjectType2 alloc] init];
[yourArray addObject: object2];

ObjectType3 *object3 = [[ObjectType3 alloc] init];
[yourArray addObject: object3];
```

This way you'll have an array with 3 items. This are 3 objects each with a different object type. Note that you have a good administration for the reading of the objects.

The following is wrong, because you are reading the first object which is of type ObjectType1, and you are assigning it to ObjectType2.

```
ObjectType2 *readingObject = [yourArray objectAtIndex:1];   // WRONG!
```

Comment: I understand it, is there any chance to use for cycle? I mean:

for (int i=0, i<100, i++) {
  // HOW TO ADD 100 OBJECTS FROM THREE CLASSES?

Comment: You can add objects using addObject as much as you like. In loops/cycles,different objects, different ViewControllers etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, it's perfectly possible:

```
NSArray *array = @[
    @"a string",
    @1337, // a NSNumber
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"anImage"],
    //... and so on
]
```

Answer (score 1):

So i think i didn't post the question proper. I have to create objects from class1 class2 etc and put them to an array. This array must contain objects from different classes

Comment: Please edit your question instead of posting an answer which is not an answer.